# Create package for someone else's repository without forking it

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I want to create a Swift Package Manager entry (manifest and modulemap files) for existing C lib repository on github.

However I don't want to fork it, add it there and maintain the fork to be up to date with original repo.

Is this a way to create a separate repository which will work as a proxy for Swift PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet. I have considered this idea, and think it would be useful, but right now in practice making an existing C lib work with the package manager usually requires moving the code around. Once we support custom code layout conventions, then I think it will become more interesting.

As a hack, you might be able to make this work by using a git submodule to reference the foreign package, and using symbolic links to make the sources appear where they need to in your "adaptor" package.

Comment: Thought about submodules, but not sure how SwiftPM handles them. It would be so cool if there would be a simplest demo project on GitHub

Comment: SwiftPM does try to automatically pull submodules. They aren't very useful yet, though, because usually once you have a submodule with sources you also need to control the conventions, and right now you can only do that by using symlinks to make sources appear where SwiftPM wants them.